# Connecting using ip address but not using web server name

Tags: ubuntu, ping, ufw

I am able to access the website of a server (running Linux Mint 18 Sylvia) that uses an http like:

http://myserver.house.pckhrest.edu

I can not do remote connection to `myserver.house.pckhrest.edu` but if I use its IP adddress then I can do the remote connection. I can ping this ip address but I can not ping using `myserver.house.pckhrest.edu`.

Is there any ufw firewall setting I am missing? I am trying to test my app and do remote web development.

Error messages:

- If I try to use m`yserver.house.pckhrest.edu` for RDP I get the message: 'Error connecting to host'.
- For ping I get `ping: unknown host`

But if I use the IP address all goes through.

Comment: Looks like a DNS problem. Show us the output of `dig a myserver.house.pckhrest.edu` and the proxy settings of the web browser which is able to access the site.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. For some reason I installed Firewalld and ufw at the same time (feel so ashamed) After I deleted Firewalld all went back to normal. I believe this could also be well if I eliminated only the ufw.
Thanks